# git clone/checkout a single SHA without history

Tags: git

Partly as an exercise, partly because it *almost* works and I feel the need to finish it...

I can `git clone $repo --branch $ref --single-branch --depth 1` and it works great for tags and heads.

I can `git pull --depth 1 $repo $sha` and it works great, as long as $sha is a FULL value.  BUT: this fails if that is abbreviated, even by 1 character.

Is there any way achieve this?  I am trying to automate git synchronization and very large repos are a problem.  Using depth 1 helps a ton, but I can't figure how to use an abbreviated SHA.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: `fatal: couldn't find remote ref 9f145865e04`.  But if I use a full SHA I get ` * branch            9f145865e04e50836bdaaf0431485346d82f8792 -> FETCH_HEAD`

Comment: You cannot use an abbreviated hash. You can only use a hash at all if the other Git is configured to let you do that (apparently this one is).

Comment: BTW this is really the same question as [Git clone --single-branch does not work for sha / commit ids?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57316783/1256452) but there is no accepted answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried using the `git -c core.abbrev=40` option, as shown in "[Making git output full (un-abbreviated) hashes for all commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21011749/6309)"

```
git -c core.abbrev=40 --branch 05f7b9c710 --single-branch --depth 1 https://github.com/auser/arepo test
```

But that still fails with:

```
Cloning into '`test`'...
warning: Could not find remote branch 05f7b9c710 to clone.
fatal: Remote branch 05f7b9c710 not found in upstream origin
```

As explained in "[`git clone --single-branch` does not work for sha / commit ids?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57317538/6309)"

> This was intentional, to allow some control over what could be fetched from repos, especially in setups where a single object db serves multiple repos.

By the way, [`uploadpack.allowAnySHA1InWant`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-uploadpackallowAnySHA1InWant) is *not* set on GitHub side.
That means even if I were to use a *full* SHA1 reference, it would still fail.

In your case, if you have control over the Git remote repository hosting server, you might set the setting to allow such a clone.